# IP Tables - Need understanding on a rule

Tags: iptables

iptables -A FORWARD -s 0/0 -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.58 -o eth1 -p TCP \ --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: can anyone please let me know how this rule would work !

Answer (score 0):

This rule is applied to packets that are traversing the firewall. It `ACCEPT`s (allows) packets that match the following properties:

- incoming interface is `eth0`
- outgoing interface is `eth1`
- any source IP
- destination IP is `192.168.1.58`
- protocol is `TCP`
- source port is between 1024 and 65535
- destination port is `80` (HTTP)

In the future, questions such as this are better suited towards SuperUser or ServerFault rather than StackOverflow.